# How well is postgres handling duplicates?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in which I store relatively big strings (10000 chars).

I will have a lot of rows (millions?), but 99% of them will have identical value of the big string.

Does anyone know if postgres has mechanism to handle this case well? (i.e. don't use gigabates of storage)

Answer (score 8):

PostgreSQL compresses internally large values. But it will **not** detect that the value in multiple rows is the same. If you want such detection, you have to do it yourself. For example using schema like:

```
CREATE TABLE big_texts (
    id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    big_text TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);


CREATE TABLE base_table (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    big_text_id INT4 NOT NULL REFERENCES big_texts (id),
    other       TEXT,
    columns     INT8,
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which unfortunately sounds like a "No, it doesn't handle it well."

Comment: @Kuba No you are wrong, it handles it you just have to put in the implementation.  You could put a trigger on your base_table have it check for existence of string and it already exits put a link to big_text. If it doesn't exists insert into big_texts and create the link on base_table.  That's one of a few ways. MD5 as Adam Gent mentions is another great way that is used in the data warehouse world all the time.

Comment: It sounds to me also like "no, it doesn't handle it well". If I create extra tables and do duplicate checks and use special IDs, then _I_ am doing the work, not PostgreSQL. The question was not, "does PostgreSQL prevent one from manually compressing multiple values manually using extra relations?" Unfortunately, even manually creating all these workaround tables, you still have the insert-if-not-exist problem (UPSERT/MERGE), the implementation of which PostgreSQL keeps delaying.

Answer (score 6):

> I will have a lot of rows (millions?), but 99% of them will have identical value of the big string.

In that case I would store unique "big strings" in a different table and just keep a reference to the right row from the other table.

Comment: Yes. It's a relational database and clearly the dependency of the big string on your main row's primary key isn't very strong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am very well aware of this solution, but that doesn't answer my question. I would prefer to not add complexity to my already complex database structure if possible

Comment: @Kuba if you don't want two tables have a look at my answer. Its how I would solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you might want to consider using MD5 as an ID. Postgres supports MD5.

Thus you could insert using @depesz modified schema:

```
CREATE TABLE big_text (
    id  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    big_text TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT big_text_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You can create the ID either programmactically in your host language or you can use Postgres to do it for you:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Then you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO big_text (id, big_text) VALUES (md5(big_text), big_text);
```

If the insert fails you already have the text in the database. Obviously you can do this in a nicer way by selecting on the md5 value first.

`10000` characters is not that massive but if you really wanted to scale you could also look into things like bloom filters and what not.

Comment: May be good, but you have to add collision detection and handling.

Comment: True but its very doubtful he would have a collision on different text particularly since they are of the same general size (0-10,000). He also said the strings are very similar which means even less possible chance of collision (collision happens when the strings are usually very different). He could use a stronger checksum if that is a problem and combine it with string size.

Comment: The birthday paradox comes into play when looking at collision probabilities across large row counts, though. It may not be likely, but it's more likely than a quick look would suggest.

Comment: Well I think its highly dependent on how much he wants to guarantee accuracy. He could always do a background check later (like some sort of async logging). I think there are so many other things that could go wrong that a false positive (ie already have the text) is probably not that bad. He can also potentially mitigate it by adding the length of the string and maybe the first character. Also a *million* rows and *10k* characters are not large numbers.

Comment: @CraigRinger: The collision probability for MD5 is $2^{-64}$ (as it is a 128-bit hash), so it should be OK [for SHA1 you get a probability of $2^{-80}$, and a publication in *Journal of Cryptology* if you happen find a collision].

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use citus data extension for postgres. In march 2021 they added a columnar storage option for tables and even table partitions. This does exactly what other answers suggest, but under the hood.
https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2021/03/06/citus-10-columnar-compression-for-postgres/